# Pandas join two dataframes, columns with the same index from the two dataframes are next to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I'm trying to join two dataframes together. They don't have any column with the same name, and I would like to make the columns with the same index in each dataframe to be put next to each other. Surprisingly, I did not find any document about this, or any existing question on StackOverflow.

So it might be easier to describe my question in an example:

df1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 | 9 |

df2:

| One | Two | Three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 | 9 |

Expected Result

| A | One | B | Two | C | Three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 | 9 | 6 | 8 | 9 |

Does anyone have an idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
    .to_numpy(),
    columns = [j for i in zip(df.columns,df2.columns) for j in i]))
```